# I want to search a keyword in a log file and get the value of that keyword

Tags: vbscript

I have a logfile with one of the lines similar to this: "2 Keyword".
I want to look for the line with the keyword and get the number (there also could be 2 digits).

I tried to stay as close as possible to the official documentation, but it does not work. Apparently the If sequence does not open.
I'm new to vbs, help or pointing in the right direction is much appriciated :)

This is my code:

```
        Dim log
        Set log = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


        Set ReadLogFile = log.OpenTextFile("C:\Folder\test.log",ForReading) 
        Do While ReadLogFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
            Textline = ReadLogFile.Readline() 
            If InStr(Textline, "Keyword") > 0 Then 
                MsgBox Textline 'just for checking
                Set RE = New RegExp
                With RE
                    .Pattern = "^[0-9]*$" ' only Numbers
                    .Global = False
                    .IgnoreCase = True
                End With
                KewordValue = RE.Execute(Textline)
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        ReadLogFile.Close
```

Comment: The reason it didnt open the if sequence was that the file was opened in the wrong format, I solved it like this:

`Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0`

`Set ReadLogFile = log.OpenTextFile("C:\Folder\test.log" ,ForReading, False, TristateTrue)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You just need to change your regex and add object extraction.

The end code would look something like this:

```
    Dim log
    Set log = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    const ForReading = 1

    Set ReadLogFile = log.OpenTextFile("C:\Folder\test.log",ForReading) 
    Do While ReadLogFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
        Textline = ReadLogFile.Readline() 
        If InStr(Textline, "Keyword") > 0 Then 
            MsgBox Textline 'just for checking
            Set RE = New RegExp
            With RE
                .Pattern = "^[0-9]{1,2}" ' this line changed
                .Global = False
                .IgnoreCase = True
            End With
            if RE.test(Textline) then 
                set regexObject = RE.Execute(Textline)
                KeyWordValue = regexObject(0)
                Exit Do
            end if 
        End If
    Loop
    ReadLogFile.Close
```

Comment: Thanks :)
There is another problem tho. The line `KeywordValue = RE.Execute(Textline)` does not seem to work. I tried it with `Set` but that is not right either. I want the value "2" in the variable "KeywordValue". how can I manage that?

Comment: you should set regexobject and then extract the item matched. I edited my response.

Comment: @GeertBellekens nice spot, i missed that line when I extracted the example, sorry for that. my first line of the code is `Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8`

Comment: thank you very much @LegoMyEgo. That makes a lot more sense than my atempts. But I get the error 800a000d type mismatch vbscript on that line:`KeyWordValue = regexObject(0)` :(

Comment: add test method to make sure that regexObject is created only when match is found.

Comment: i dont't know why i kept getting the error, i solved it like this:
`If RE.Test(Textline) Then`
`SET regexObjekt = RE.Execute(Textline)`
`For Each Match in regexObjekt`
`KeyWordValue = Match.value `
`Exit Do`
`Next`
`End If`